# Thin iron wires vs Iron Pan

Tags: thermodynamics

It doesn't make sense that a fine Iron wires have more surface area than an iron pan. How is it possible mathematically?

Comment: Are you asking about the combined surface area of all of the "fine iron wires" in the world, vs. the surface area of just one pan? Are you talking about just one fine iron wire? and if so, which one? Or, maybe you are asking about a _ratio_ (e.g., surface area per gram of iron?) I think your question needs more detail. You could start by telling us where you _heard_ that fine iron wires have more surface area than an iron pan.

Answer (score 1):

on a *per unit of mass* basis, this is true, here's how to see why.

Imagine you have a square cube with side length l of iron which you are going to heat and beat into a frying pan. In this example, the pan is going to weigh exactly what the chunk of raw iron did, because we won't be cutting anything off it. its surface area is 6l^2.

Then we heat it and beat it until it becomes a flattened rectangle 1/2(l) tall and 2(l) wide. Its surface area is 7l^2, but it *weighs the same* as the initial cube.

The more we flatten it out, the more its surface area grows- even though its mass *stays the same*.

If we pound the cube of iron into a paper-thin sheet, its surface area becomes huge, and if we then tear that sheet of iron into tiny strips to make it into wire, its surface area becomes even more greatly magnified.